# How can i make both iptables/ip6tables run at startup?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I have two differents set of rules in two files, one is dedicated to ipv4 and the other for ipv6. 
To make them persistant I use the if-pre-up/if-post-down script :

```
#! /bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/FWrulestwo
ip6tables-restore < /etc/FWvsixrulestwo
exit 0
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/FWrulestwo
ip6tables-save -c > /etc/FWvsixrulestwo
exit 0
```

The result of this when I reboot is that all the chains from both firewall have no rules and the policies are in drop mode.

Before that I tried with only one file which include IPv4 and IPv6 rules, It doesn't work as well.

Can I make it work that way or I have to use the iptables-persistant technique?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this link maybe can help you

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Saving_iptables

Comment: Yes this is the documentation that I used and it work fine if you have only one type of ip family (IPv4 or IPV6)